# Is "get a better understanding about some concept/mechanism" a grammatical, idiomatic and clear expression?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57885720/10449636) just now.

> I am trying to get a better understanding about this procedure of Python code to be generated.

similarly people may say these

get a better understanding about calculus, get a better understanding about the mechanisms of memory, ...

Is "get a better understanding about some concept/mechanism" a grammatical, idiomatic and clear expression?

Comment: The idiomatic preposition that follows *understanding* in that phrase is *of*, and by a large margin at that should the metric be the frequency of occurrence in Google's corpus (represented by the [Google Books Ngram Viewer chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+a+better+understanding+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing)).

Comment: This is one of those relatively uncommon contexts where the older / more formal way of phrasing things is actually ***shorter and simpler*** than the idiomatic standard today. If Charles Dickens were speaking, he'd probably say *I am trying **to better understand** this procedure...* Note that although ***trying to get a better understanding*** is fine, there's definitely something wrong with ***this procedure of Python code to be generated***. But I don't understand exactly what you *mean* there, so I can't say how it *should* be expressed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is clear and understandable but it's not clear from your example exactly what the object of the understanding is. The preposition 'of' sounds better to my ear when talking about a noun. For instance

> I'm trying to get a better understanding of this concept.
>   I'm trying to get a better understanding of the Python procedure.

I would use 'about' when the object is a phrase like 'how this procedure in Python code is generated'.

> I'm trying to get a better understanding about how this procedure in Python code is generated.
>   I'm trying to get a better understanding about the way this Python procedure is generated.